# Travel to Mexico on B1/B2 in old passport

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, mexico

I am an Indian citizen. I am currently in US on B1/B2 visa. I plan to visit Mexico for 5 days. I have a valid passport. b1/B2 visa is valid but stamped in old passport. I plan to take both passports. Any advice from people in similar situation is appreciated.

Comment: You have a valid passport and a valid visa, there should be no problems